# Fragment shader mixes uv coordinates

Tags: metal, fragment-shader

I try to understand how shaders work, just first steps. With some tutorials I made a view, vertex shader and fragment shader. Wow. It works.

But when I started to play with it, I found something really surprising, and I don't know how to deal with it. And WHY it behaves like this.

There are vertices passed to the vertex shader:

```
    let vertices = [
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( 1, 1, 0)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( 1,-1, 0)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3(-1,-1, 0)), 
       
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( 1, 1, 0)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( -1, 1, 0)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3(-1,-1, 0))
    ]
```

Beautiful rectangle I can see. Wow, if I return color from from fragment shader, without calculations, changes...

BUT, when I start to play with shader

```
fragment float4 fragmentShader(RasterizerData input [[stage_in]],
                               float2 uv [[point_coord]]) {
                           
    float2 coord = (uv - float2(0.5)) * 2;
    return (sin(coord.x*10)/2)+ 0.5;
}
```

a result is different than I expected:

[image: should be sinus wave on x axis]

I expected just sinus wave on x-axis.

When I play with vertices order, I can have different result:

[image: Wrrr]

or

[image]

uv coordinates are always „wrong”?
What's wrong? What I missed?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a link to the tutorial you are following.

Comment: There are few tutorials about „how to draw your first triangle”. Just setting up environment, step by step, nothing extra. I cannot understand, how it's possible that fragment shader coordinates depends on vertices.

Comment: Sure, but I want to compare your results and what you've done with what you're following. I can't do that without link(s).

Comment: I made repo on Github: https://github.com/typoland/PlayWithMetal. I think is best I can do.

Comment: I need to see precisely what you are expecting the results to look like for one.

Comment: in this case: black and white sinus wave across x-axis. Both triangles in same coordinates space. Not rotated, not translated. I just want to „draw” on them like on some uniform canvas.

Comment: Your project has the error: `Use of unknown directive '#Preview'`. I don't use SwiftUI so not sure whats up with that. I could figure it out, or make a new project but I don't want to solve an issue to solve an issue.

Comment: That's only available in Xcode 15

Comment: @Joshua, You can remove #Preview section, it just allows Xcode to make preview on canvas...

Answer (score 1):

`point_coord` is for point primitives, meaning `MTLPrimitiveTypePoint`. It is undefined for triangles.

For triangles, what you actually want is to provide or calculate a UV that the rasterizer will interpolate across your triangle. UV is a 2 component coordinate with components going from 0 to 1 that's usually used to sample textures. In your case, UV would be (0, 0) in top left corner and (1, 1) in bottom right corner of the screen.

So your code would look like this. In a bridging header you would have a struct

```
struct Vertex {
    vector_float3 position;
    vector_float2 texCoord;
}
```

then in Swift

```
let vertices = [
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( 1, 1, 0), texCoord:vector_float2(0, 0)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( 1,-1, 0), texCoord:vector_float2(0, 1)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3(-1,-1, 0), texCoord:vector_float2(1, 1)), 
       
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( 1, 1, 0), texCoord:vector_float2(0, 0)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3( -1, 1, 0), position:vector_float2(1, 0)),
        Vertex(position:vector_float3(-1,-1, 0), texCoord:vector_float2(1, 1))
    ]
```

then you would need to set up a vertex attribute in the `MTLVertexDescriptor`, then read that attribute in your vertex shader and then your fragment shader would look like

```
fragment float4 fragmentShader(RasterizerData input [[stage_in]]) {
                           
    float2 coord = (input.uv - float2(0.5)) * 2;
    return (sin(coord.x*10)/2)+ 0.5;
}
```

Or, if you are trying to do a fullscreen fragment shader, you may even just use `vertex_id` and a predefined array of positions and UVs. Keep in mind that snippet below uses one big triangle that covers the whole screen instead of two smaller adjacent triangles, but it's easy to modify.

```
constant array<float3, 3> fullscreenTrianglePositions =
{
    float3{-1, -1, 0},
    float3{-1,  3, 0},
    float3{ 3, -1, 0},
};

constant array<float2, 3> fullscreenTriangleTexCoords =
{
    float2{0,  1},
    float2{0, -1},
    float2{2,  1},
};

struct FullscreenVertexOut
{
    float4 position [[ position ]];
    float2 texCoord;
};

vertex FullscreenVertexOut FullscreenTriangleVertex(ushort vertexId [[ vertex_id ]])
{
    FullscreenVertexOut out;
    out.position.xyz = fullscreenTrianglePositions[vertexId];
    out.position.w = 1;
    out.texCoord = fullscreenTriangleTexCoords[vertexId];
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Great, but there is something I don't really understand:  Vertex(position ... , position:: ....) — same labels and double colon. Typo? C++? I have a Swift struct Vertex which has position defined as vector_float3.

Comment: Oh, I mixed up my syntax. Sorry. I'm gonna edit my answer.